# How can I easily make a java application invisible to the user?

Tags: java

I have developed a Java aplication that is currently being run by double-clicking on a ".bat" file that does something like "java -jar proy.jar". This application just listens on a port and writes to a database, so it does not have any user interface (such as a window). I need this application to run as in background mode, or as it were a service, but I don't really anything more than that. It's enough if the application is run in a way that is not noticeable by the user, so that the user is not bothered and so the application can not be mistakenly closed. By the way, this will be run on an specific computer so it's okay if I have to do any manual configuration ir order to make this work. Also, I need this application to run on startup.

Any help/tips regarding this?
In advance, thank you very much for your help!

Regards,

Pedro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `javaw.exe` instead of `java.exe` and you will not get a console window.

from the [java.sun.com](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there is no associated console window. Use javaw when you don't want a command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some reason.

EDIT:

A .bat will start a console.  If you can live with a console up for a fraction of a second, you can preface your call to `javaw` with `start`.  This will spawn another console-less process for `javaw` and allow the console-*ful* bat to exit.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Do you mean to change the line inside the .bat file? I'm still getting that window shown when I do that.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the edit. This works great for me. Any tip about how to easily make it run on startup on Windows 7? Thanks again.

Comment: Use Task Scheduler. You can even just execute javaw instead of .bat. No console popup anymore.

Comment: @Pedro: If you can do away with your ".bat" file, do so. Just put "javaw -jar proy.jar" in your a shortcut and double-click on that.

Comment: To run javaw with arguments without seeing a console window, right-click your desktop and say New->Shortcut.  Specify javaw along with whatever arguments you want.  Remember to set the working directory.  Copy this to the Startup folder in your Start Menu as an easy way to run it on startup.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your application as a System Tray icon (Java 1.6) if you are targeting Windows environment. Allow a context-sensitive menu trigger when clicking on the System Tray icon for the user to select a few options.

Comment: That's a good tip. I will probably do this in the future to provide the user with a way to interact with the service. Thanks for your help!